# Perl doesn't print @INC with -I option in one line program

Tags: perl

This one works:

```
pavel@x79:/data/projects/zone-service$ perl -E "print \"@INC\";"
/etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .
```

And same command with `-I` option doesn't (show empty output):

```
pavel@x79:/data/projects/zone-service$ perl -E -Ilib "print \"@INC\";"
```

Why ?

Comment: Try `perl -Ilib -E "print \"@INC\""` and then take a guess.

Comment: Enable warnings, especially on one-liners :)

Comment: The `-e` or `-E` switch has to come after any other command line switches. Strangely I could not find this documented clearly in [`perlrun`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: It does not have to come after. Run `perl -E 'say "@INC"' -I/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just mixed up the usage of parameters, code must be written after `-E` parameter:

```
perl -Ilib -E "print \"@INC\""
```